# Oracle AND condtion is not giving right output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table which have data like

```
|A    |   B    |
|-----|--------|
|089  |     09 |
|088  |     18 |
|089  |     00 |
|087  |     00 |
|088  |     00 |
```

*Col A and B data type is char(3).

**Desired Output :**
I need output which doesn't have combination of (A=088 and B=00) AND (A=089 and B=00)
So desired output should be

```
|A     |    B    |
|------|---------|
|089   |   09    |
|088   |   18    |
|087   |   00    |
```

I tried with below query but its not working

```
select * from Table where (A <> '088' AND B <> '00')
```

Comment: You should start by removing the 0 before '088'. In a character column, that zero will be treated as a character, not as a meaningless leading zero.

Comment: So, what are you actually getting?   You never showed us that.

Comment: As a side note, if B is defined as `char(3)` and you insert the value `'00'`, then Oracle will store the value blank-padded as `'00 '`. Now, will it match the literal value `'00'` or not? Actually it will. But it won't match a `varchar2` `'00'`. Are you confident that you understand `char` comparison rules? I suggest avoiding char and sticking to the normal varchar2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just code it as you write it in plain English:

```
select * 
from Table 
where Not((A='088' and B='000') Or (A='089' and B='000'))
```

Comment: your query output is with the combination (088,00) and (089,00)...if i use where Not((A='088' and B='00') Or (A='089' and B='00'))

Comment: @vim it's not clear in your question if the leading 0s are required or not. Does it work with them?

Comment: leading 0 is require

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement can be written as:

```
NOT (A = '088' AND B = '00') AND NOT (A = '089' AND B = '00')
```

which is [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to:

```
(A <> '088' OR B <> '00') AND (A <> '089' OR B <> '00')
```

and finally simplified to:

```
(B <> '00') OR (A <> '088' AND A <> '089')
```

or with the operator `IN`:

```
(B <> '00') OR (A NOT IN ('088', '089'))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a0ed04b2c639c2553e1c36501a55d047) (for MySql but it is standard SQL)

Answer (score 2):

> I need output which doesn't have combination of (A=088 and B=00) AND (A=089 and B=00)

Oracle supports tuples, so you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where (A, B) not in ( ('088', '00'), ('089', '00) );
```

I assume the values are strings because they have a zero as the leftmost digit.

Answer (score 0):

If those really are string columns, then '088' is not the same as '88'.